# How to run Multiple Servers as one without using different ports for each?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, server

I have multiple ASP.NET servers which run on the same IP address but different ports. They run in Microsoft IIS and together make a multi-tenant application. Examples of these servers are shown in the table below. There are more than 15 servers. Since there are many ports open, it raises a security concern that the application is vulnerable to attacks.

```
+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+
| Server     |    Home   | Authentication | User Management |   Others  |
+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+
| IP Address | 127.0.0.1 |    127.0.0.1   |    127.0.0.1    | 127.0.0.1 |
+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+
| Port       |     80    |       97       |       120       |           |
+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

At this application, you can access the homepage on port 80, and when you click the login button, the `Home` server redirects you to the `Authentication` server on port 97. Although it is easier to manage separate server projects, it's not good for production.

Can you suggest your solution, what architecture I should use instead of the multi-ports issue?

Comment: You could set up `nginx`. Then Nginx would take all incoming requests and depending on the URL path forward it to the right service. So `/auth` would go to your Authentication service, `/user` would go to user management and all others would go to Home. Like Marc says, that doesn't really improve security. It does look nicer though.

Comment: "Since there are many ports open, it raises a security concern that the application is vulnerable to attacks." - how does that follow? if the ports are all doing the same thing, one port is exactly as vulnerable as 20. The number of ports is largely irrelevant (although it may be inconvenient for your firewall configuration) - it is *what they do* that makes them vulnerable (or not)

Comment: @HansKilian: I have looked into `NginX`, it is a viable solution however when changing the config manually, you have to restart `NginX`, thus interrupting the application which is not good for production. I tried to change the config dynamically in case some server URL changed, but I was not able to. Do you have another solution?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I thought when having multiple ports open, you increase exposure and increase the chances of an attack. Also, the servers are all not the same, one might be more vulnerable than the others.

Comment: You can reload the nginx configuration using the command `nginx reload` which doesn't have any downtime. In production you'd also want to have mulitple nginx instances running so your whole site doesn't go down in case a single instance fails.

Comment: @Ibrahim "one might be more vulnerable than the others" if you have a vulnerability, you have a vulnerability - so: go fix that; the number of ports *by itself* isn't relevant there

Comment: @HansKilian: I think that way might actually work for me. Reloading without downtime solves changing the config dynamically. Thanks Hans Kilian.

Answer (score 0):

You can uniquely ID servers not only by the **IP** and **port** but also by its **name**.

I suggest you use the `hosts` file locally or a DNS server.
For example on your `hosts` file you can have:

```
127.0.0.1 home.lan
127.0.0.1 users.lan
```

Either run on port 80, you can browse
http://home.lan to reach the home server or http://users.lan to reach the user's server.

On-Premises (PROD) environment or cloud you must setup *your* DNS

Your question does not describe how your solution is used: local DMZ? Azure? AWS?

Other possible solutions can be:

- Docker with or without `Nginx`.
- nginx in your local environment.

Comment: I'm studying your solution and will give you feedback soon. Thanks